# How can I start up a new Channel?

Tags: vlogger-go-viral

I saw that my channel menu states that this is my #1 channel, so I guess we should be able to start up new channels. I checked loads of ingame menus but failed to find where I can start a new Channel. I want to start new channels to make more money, how can I do it?

[image: Channel Menu]

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you cannake a channel when you become the number channel in the world 
http://www.chaptercheats.com/qna/android/351165/Vlogger-Go-Viral-Clicker-Answers.htm?qid=139143